# Azure Function writing to CosmosDB and error handling

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-functions

I have written an Azure Function that persists data to a Cosmos collection:

```js
const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
    try {
        if (req.body) {
            const body: Body = req.body

            context.bindings.cosmosDocument = JSON.stringify(body);
            context.res = {
                status: 200,
                body: 'Successfully persisted document'
            };
        }
    } catch (error) {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: 'Colliding id'
        }
    }
}
```

I am handling errors [according to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages#use-structured-error-handling).

My payload looks like this:

```
{
    "shipmentId": "shipmentId",
    "timestamp": 1586327829354,
    "totalVolume": 1,
    "totalWeight": 1,
    "packages": [{
        "packageId": "courierPackageId",
        "shipmentId": "shipmentId",
        "weight:": 1000,
        "dimensions": {
            "length": 100,
            "width": 100,
            "height": 100
        }
    }]
}
```

However, when I try to persist something that will have a colliding id in the database, that error is not caught.

I see the following error:

> Entity with the specified id already exists in the system

And when I call this trigger through Postman, I get status 500 and no message body.

In [this issue on Github](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/891), a solution is suggested for C#.

How can I handle this exception and give the API user a meaningful message? What is the usual approach when building APIs in Azure Function and handling errors produced by output bindings?

Comment: Can you show the body you post?

Comment: @BowmanZhu see my updated post. The works, and it rejects duplicates as it should, I just want to be able to act on it.

Comment: Works fine on my side, I am trying to check it out.

Comment: The request body will be saved to a random id, if you want to update, you should specify the id in the request body.

Comment: I want to have the generated id, my issue is that I cannot notify an end user if a collision occurs. If a error happens downstream in cosmos output, it seems to be out of my control.

Comment: There is no such error at all in my side, and I will never walk into the part of the 'catch'. If I specify an identical id, it will be updated without throwing an error. From your error, it seems that you are performing an add operation? In my case, if the id is the same, the update operation will be performed, and then no error will be thrown. If no id is specified, the id will be equal to a GUID (this value is generated based on the current machine and time plus some other values, absolutely unique).

Comment: That's weird... I purposefully left out the id to have it generated. I don't really know what operation I'm performing by assigning the value to `cosmosDocument`, it doesn't seem clear from the bindings either. If it is that unique, it is weird that I manage to get the duplicates error. I just repeat the process of posting the same payload twice from Postman and that causes the duplicate exception for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my side, it works fine. I can upload and also update.

This is the code of my function app:

**index.ts:**

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions"

const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
    context.log('HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    const name = (req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name));

    try {
        if (req.body) {
            const body: Body = req.body

            context.bindings.employeeDocument = JSON.stringify(body);
            context.res = {
                status: 200,
                body: 'Successfully persisted document'
            };
        }
    } catch (error) {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: 'Colliding id'
        }
    }

    if (name) {
        context.res = {
            // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
            body: "Hello " + (req.query.name || req.body.name)
        };
    }
    else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body"
        };
    }
};

export default httpTrigger;
```

**function.json:**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "name": "employeeDocument",
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "databaseName": "ToDoList",
      "collectionName": "Items",
      "createIfNotExists": true,
      "connectionStringSetting": "MyAccount_COSMOSDB",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "scriptFile": "../dist/HttpTrigger1/index.js"
}
```

And This is the postman:(I have put the json file in the test.txt)

[image]

**test.txt:**

```
{
    "id": "934a2153-fdb1-40e3-9e90-61c43fcef220",
    "shipmentId": "shipmentId2",
    "timestamp": 1586327829354,
    "totalVolume": 1,
    "totalWeight": 1,
    "packages": [{
        "packageId": "courierPackageId",
        "shipmentId": "shipmentId",
        "weight:": 1000,
        "dimensions": {
            "length": 100,
            "width": 100,
            "height": 100
        }
    }]
}
```

In the case of the same id, if you change other parts and then trigger the function, azure cosmosdb will be updated accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I will get back to you as soon as I've tried some more in my own code.

Comment: @jokarl This is [my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wo2xS.png). I have post the same body 5 times to cosmosdb and it throw no errors. In my case, the id is automatically generated and is the only GUID. Maybe we have some settings directly different, I can provide if you need.

Comment: This is weird. I started my code again and I can no longer reproduce the error I got in my original question. Now I get the exact same behavior as you describe, and I see all unique items in my collection. If I explicitly specify Id as you did above, it updates an existing item without any issues.